# "Kotlin not configured" error on Android 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, android-studio-3.5

I've updated Android Studio from 3.0 to 3.5.3 and receiving this error.

> Kotlin not configured

[image]

Dependencies used in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.60'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
}
```

Tried doing below tricks but nothing worked:

1. Restarting
2. Clean and Rebuild
3. Invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: Kotlin version should be "1.3.61"

Comment: Tried this but my current gradle version is 2.7 which doesn't get along with the version you've mentioned.

Comment: Any reason why you're an extremely outdated version of Gradle? The current stable version is 6.0.1.

Comment: @Edric its because the project i'm trying to run is compatible with this version of gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and tried compiling with below code in build.gradle at buildscript level

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.14.449'
classpath 'org.hidetake:gradle-ssh-plugin:1.1.3'
}
}

apply plugin: "kotlin" // or apply plugin: "kotlin2js" if targeting JavaScript
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: "org.hidetake.ssh"



repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.60'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
}

remotes {
edison {
host = 'host'
user = "root"
agent = true
}
}

task deploy(dependsOn: distTar) << {
ssh.run {
session(remotes.host) {
put from: '.tar', into: '.tar'
execute '.tar'
}
}
}
```

Also let the dependencies you've mentioned above be same.

If you get any further issues after compiling your gradle try using Spotbugs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to use this within my build.gradle and it works fine.
But now a new error appears i suspect its because i'm using Findbugs, do you by any chance know were would i get implementation on Spotbugs please ?

Comment: Please find below link explaining Spotbugs implementation:
https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/issues/90

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Go to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Kotlin press uninstall) and after a restart of Android Studio reinstall the plugin.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, but that didn't work for me. Still receiving same error.